# Uploading Stream to Aws S3 not working Properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to Upload stream to AWS s3. now my File Manager can upload stream of objects on server without any load or bloating. But when it comes to AWS s3 it returns successful response and even AWS SDK is not reporting anything about misconfiugration it also returns Successful Upload so my File Manager is fine But. Problem is that when i take a look on AWS Console i only see path of given file not file itself..For better Understanding Please take a look at following code and Images.

## Stream to Upload (File)

```
ReadStream {
  _readableState: ReadableState {
    objectMode: false,
    highWaterMark: 65536,
    buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
    length: 0,
    pipes: null,
    pipesCount: 0,
    flowing: null,
    ended: false,
    endEmitted: false,
    reading: false,
    sync: true,
    needReadable: false,
    emittedReadable: false,
    readableListening: false,
    resumeScheduled: false,
    emitClose: false,
    autoDestroy: false,
    destroyed: false,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    awaitDrain: 0,
    readingMore: false,
    decoder: null,
    encoding: null,
    [Symbol(kPaused)]: null
  },
  readable: true,
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    end: [ [Function], [Function: remove] ],
    error: [Function],
    close: [Function: remove]
  },
  _eventsCount: 3,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  path: '/tmp/capacitor-7957c2e3611868508c7ac8ec64c1a7c2.tmp',
  fd: null,
  flags: 'r',
  mode: 438,
  start: undefined,
  end: Infinity,
  autoClose: true,
  pos: undefined,
  bytesRead: 0,
  closed: false,
  name: undefined,
  _writeStream: WriteStream {
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: true,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: true,
      ended: true,
      finished: true,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: true,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: false,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      bufferedRequest: null,
      lastBufferedRequest: null,
      pendingcb: 0,
      prefinished: true,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      bufferedRequestCount: 0,
      corkedRequestsFree: [Object]
    },
    writable: false,
    _events: [Object: null prototype] { error: [Function] },
    _eventsCount: 1,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    path: '/tmp/capacitor-7957c2e3611868508c7ac8ec64c1a7c2.tmp',
    fd: 30,
    flags: 'w',
    mode: 438,
    start: undefined,
    autoClose: false,
    pos: undefined,
    bytesWritten: 46355,
    closed: false,
    _readStreams: Set { [Circular] },
    error: null,
    _cleanupSync: [Function],
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kIsPerformingIO)]: false
  },
  error: null,
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  [Symbol(kIsPerformingIO)]: false
}
```

## FileManager AWS S3 Code

```
if (this.configuration.Aws && this.configuration.Aws.s3 && this.configuration.Aws.s3.accessKey && this.configuration.Aws.s3.secretKey) {
          // Local variable.
          let _Aws, _StreamUpload

          // Upload file to s3
          _Aws = new Aws.S3({
            'accessKeyId': this.configuration.Aws.s3.accessKey,
            'secretAccessKey': this.configuration.Aws.s3.secretKey
          })

          /*
           * Only successful upload
           * reply to client else report
           * failure.
           */
          if (!_.isEmpty(_Aws) && !(_Aws instanceof Error)) {
            console.log('erw---rer>>', file)
            /*
             * Steam upload to aws.
             * upload file to aws.
             */
            _StreamUpload = await new Promise((__resolve, __reject) =>
            // Upload file stream to aws s3
              _Aws.upload({
                'Bucket': this.configuration.Aws.s3.bucketName,
                'Key': path,
                'Body': file
              }, (error, __data) => error instanceof Error ? __reject(error) : __resolve(__data)))

            /*
             * Only return _StreamUpload if
             * uploading didnt contain any error.
             */
            if (_StreamUpload && !(_StreamUpload instanceof Error)) {
              // Return upload.
              return { 'storageType': 's3', 'path': _StreamUpload.Location }
            }

            // Report failure.
            return _StreamUpload
          }

          // Report failure.
          return _.isEmpty(_Aws) ? new Error('UPLOAD_FAILED(AWS)') : _Aws
        }
```

## AWS S3 Response

```
{
  ETag: '"1ea966ff33714024a163d51e06b9bad8"',
  Location: 'https://truckpe.s3.amazonaws.com//ck7ef9esk000k0758t9r3mngq/1585455100505/',
  key: '/ck7ef9esk000k0758t9r3mngq/1585455100505/',
  Key: '/ck7ef9esk000k0758t9r3mngq/1585455100505/',
  Bucket: 'truckpe'
}
```

## AWS S3 Console Screen Shot

[image]